# How to execute cmd command in java?

Tags: java, cmd, gdal

I want to execute this command

```
D:/Projects/GDAL/ogr2ogr.exe -f "MapInfo File" D:/Projects/GDAL/r/output_test.tab PG:"host=localhost user=postgres password=123456 dbname=postgis" -sql "SELECT * from filedata WHERE num=1"
```

I tried this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "D:/Projects/GDAL/ogr2ogr.exe -f \"MapInfo File\" D:/Projects/GDAL/r/output_test.tab PG:\"host=localhost user=postgres password=123456 dbname=postgis\" -sql \"SELECT * from filedata WHERE num=1\""});
```

I got no errors, but nothing is happening.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: You are not reall using DOS, are you?

Comment: exec already executes the command right? do you need to call cmd.exe?

Comment: i just want to this command executed.

Comment: your quotes are not correct ... you cannot write a string literal using single quotes + inside a string literal double quotes have to be escaped like this `\"` ... also take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html ... it is more handy

Comment: Sorry im put anotther cde line in question. Now is correct. But `\"` not helped.

Comment: That remind me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2147562/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add '/C':

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "D:/Projects/GDAL/ogr2ogr.exe -f \"MapInfo File\" D:/Projects/GDAL/r/output_test.tab PG:\"host=localhost user=postgres password=123456 dbname=postgis\" -sql \"SELECT * from filedata WHERE num=1\""})
```

Answer (score 4):

Read this: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html and go through each suggestion step by step.

The Process API is notorious for gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your return values:

```
String command = ""; // Your command
Process installproc = installcommand.execute();

StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();

installproc.waitForProcessOutput(out, err);
if (out.length() > 0) System.out.println("out:\n$out".toString());
if (err.length() > 0) System.out.println("err:\n$err".toString());

if(installproc.exitValue() != 0) {
throw new Exception("");
}
```

This is just sample code I did not test it in any way.

This should you give some hints about what the error is.