# Display log information for a specific person in Git

Tags: java, git

I'm working on Java to show some information from Git repository.I'm using "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" to execute the command.

So when I write

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git --git-dir=/home/gh/git/.git --work-tree=/home/gh/git log");
```

it works perfect

However, I need to get the log information for a specific person, so when I write the following statement, it doesn't display any result

```
String activeDeveloper = "Carlos Rica";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git --git-dir=/home/ghadeer/git/.git --work-tree=/home/ghadeer/git log --author=" + activeDeveloper);
```

anyone knows how what is the problem?

Comment: Disregarding Java for the moment, how would you enter that command to search for a specific person *on the command line*? Make sure you can get the correct results there before trying to put it inside Java.

Comment: This is the way to enter the command on the terminal. "git --git-dir=/home/ghadeer/git/.git --work-tree=/home/ghadeer/git log  --author="Carlos Rica"). And, it works perfect as well. But, it doesn't in Java !!!

Comment: You have spaces in your developer name. If this gets passed to `exec` is will be treated as two arguments, and if you don't have a developer called Carlos (with no last name), `git log` can't return results. You must quote the name correctly to do that.

Comment: `String activeDeveloper = "\"Carlos Rica\"";`

Comment: Jochen, you are right; it doesn't work because of the space. But, what I can do to make it work even if the name has the space?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Following [mazaneicha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638764/mazaneicha)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918140/display-log-information-for-a-specific-person-in-git#comment15869650_11918140), the usual way to add those quotes around the author name would be:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git --git-dir=/home/ghadeer/git/.git --work-tree=/home/ghadeer/git log --author=\"" + activeDeveloper + "\"");
```

However, if this still doesn't work, you would need to tokenize the all command, as illustrated in the "[`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146727/runtime-getruntime-exec/2147562#2147562)" SO question.