# How can i run git commands from java?

Tags: java, git

I was able to run the git commands via shell script. But is there any possible mean by which I can call each git statement i.e `git show <SHA>:<file>` directly from java ?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382979/calling-git-from-java-with-command-line). I believe this might help you. Thanks,
M

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to execute git commands directly.

Or, you could use [JGit](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit), which is a Java implementation of git.